# How to generate XMLA script of an SSAS tabular model using SQL job?

Tags: sql, ssas, ssas-tabular, sql-job

We are using SQL jobs to deploy SSAS models deployed in UAT server to production server. Two steps we are currently following are:

1. Sync model of UAT to production.
2. Process (full) the production model.

Now we want to add another step where we take the backup of the "create or replace to" script of production ssas model before it is synced with UAT model. Is it possible to do this via SQL job? If not what other feasible option do we have?

I have tried the profiler trace to see what code is running behind when we right click and generate the create script but it wasn't helpful. Any tips or guidance appreciated.

Comment: Where do you take backup ? Where do you want to store the xmla script ?

Comment: Our jobs are currently created at another database server but access isn't a constraint so we can store the XMLA script as a file at any server's physical location of choice (UAT, prod, DB). Currently backups of codes are taken manually and stored at local and backups of SSAS db aren't being taken anywhere as such.